# Included JQuery not Working when using <script src="">

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, src

I'm echoing the contents of a JS file with PHP (makes me feel icky) to get around the fact that I'm unable to use the definitions in it otherwise. The includes are in the head.

```
<!--this works... the correct way doesnt-->
        <script>
            <?= require_once($base_path . "/public_html/js/validation.js"); ?>
        </script>
<!--todo this does not work-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/validation.js"></script>
```

I've checked the response and it is 200 OK.

[image]

Other JS files I've included this way work. The file is JQuery that requires `$(document).ready()`. A snippet of the JS I'm trying to include is as follows...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on("change keydown paste input", 'input[type="tel"]', function () {
        var oldtel = $(this).val().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        $(this).val(oldtel);
        if ($(this).val().length > 3) {
            var tel = oldtel.slice(0, 3) + "-" + oldtel.slice(3, 10);
            $(this).val(tel);
        }

        if (oldtel.length >= 7) {
            var tel = oldtel.slice(0, 3) + "-" + oldtel.slice(3, 6) + "-" + oldtel.slice(6, 10);
            $(this).val(tel);
        }
    });
    ...
```

Comment: my guess is that you have cached outdated version of validation.js in your browser. Try to reload with ctrl+f5 or put a breakpoint in your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A common problem which occurs due to outdated cache, reload with:** `ctrl + f5`